# php-fpm process get stuck fetching S3 Objects in CurlMultiHandler

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, curl, fpm

So we use AWS ECS tasks to process our reports in production system. Now it seems that each Sunday, when we process most of these reports some of these tasks seem to get stuck and not do anything. If we restart php-fpm service, problem disappears.

I have SSH'ed into one of these tasks and used tools like ps, strace and phpspy to try and identify the problem. If I run ps aux, I can see around 20 php-fpm child processes. Running strace on each one of these and only a single child process is returning me some data. Here is that strace shows me:

```
poll([{fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=14, events=POLLIN}], 2, 1000) = 0 (Timeout)
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[PIPE], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f1884c06040}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[PIPE], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f1884c06040}, NULL, 8) = 0
poll([{fd=19, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[PIPE], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f1884c06040}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[PIPE], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f1884c06040}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[PIPE], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f1884c06040}, NULL, 8) = 0
poll([{fd=14, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[PIPE], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f1884c06040}, NULL, 8) = 0
poll([{fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=14, events=POLLIN}], 2, 1000) = 0 (Timeout)
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[PIPE], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f1884c06040}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[PIPE], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f1884c06040}, NULL, 8) = 0
```

Running phpspy on the same PID, I can see same piece of code being executed, almost as if it's stuck in infinite loop:

```
0 curl_multi_select <internal>:-1
1 GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler::tick /srv/www/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlMultiHandler.php:101
2 GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler::execute /srv/www/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlMultiHandler.php:136
3 GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::invokeWaitFn /srv/www/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:243
4 GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::waitIfPending /srv/www/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:219
5 GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::invokeWaitList /srv/www/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:262
6 GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::waitIfPending /srv/www/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:219
7 GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::invokeWaitList /srv/www/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:262
8 GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::waitIfPending /srv/www/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:219
9 GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::wait /srv/www/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:60
10 GuzzleHttp\Promise\EachPromise::GuzzleHttp\Promise\{closure} /srv/www/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/EachPromise.php:109
11 GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::invokeWaitFn /srv/www/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:243
12 GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::waitIfPending /srv/www/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:219
13 GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::wait /srv/www/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:60
14 PiExt\S3Client\S3Client::fetchObjectsInParallel /srv/www/library/pi-ext/s3-client/src/S3Client.php:169
15 PiExt\S3Client\S3Client::getObjects /srv/www/library/pi-ext/s3-client/src/S3Client.php:99
```

So judging from this stacktrace, I can see that it is continuously trying to get S3 Object using Curl. If I use lsof command on same PID, then I cann see all these connections to S3:

```
php-fpm8.  39 www-data   14u  IPv4 322974      0t0     TCP ip-10-0-0-201.eu-west-1.compute.internal:34416->s3-eu-west-1-r-w.amazonaws.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
php-fpm8.  39 www-data   16u  IPv4 322980      0t0     TCP ip-10-0-0-201.eu-west-1.compute.internal:34428->s3-eu-west-1-r-w.amazonaws.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php-fpm8.  39 www-data   17u  IPv4 322979      0t0     TCP ip-10-0-0-201.eu-west-1.compute.internal:34426->s3-eu-west-1-r-w.amazonaws.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php-fpm8.  39 www-data   18u  IPv4 322975      0t0     TCP ip-10-0-0-201.eu-west-1.compute.internal:34418->s3-eu-west-1-r-w.amazonaws.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php-fpm8.  39 www-data   19u  IPv4 322964      0t0     TCP ip-10-0-0-201.eu-west-1.compute.internal:34396->s3-eu-west-1-r-w.amazonaws.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
php-fpm8.  39 www-data   20u  IPv4 322971      0t0     TCP ip-10-0-0-201.eu-west-1.compute.internal:34410->s3-eu-west-1-r-w.amazonaws.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php-fpm8.  39 www-data   21u  IPv4 322976      0t0     TCP ip-10-0-0-201.eu-west-1.compute.internal:34420->s3-eu-west-1-r-w.amazonaws.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php-fpm8.  39 www-data   22u  IPv4 322977      0t0     TCP ip-10-0-0-201.eu-west-1.compute.internal:34422->s3-eu-west-1-r-w.amazonaws.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php-fpm8.  39 www-data   23u  IPv4 322965      0t0     TCP ip-10-0-0-201.eu-west-1.compute.internal:34398->s3-eu-west-1-r-w.amazonaws.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
php-fpm8.  39 www-data   24u  IPv4 322981      0t0     TCP ip-10-0-0-201.eu-west-1.compute.internal:34430->s3-eu-west-1-r-w.amazonaws.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php-fpm8.  39 www-data   25u  IPv4 322966      0t0     TCP ip-10-0-0-201.eu-west-1.compute.internal:34400->s3-eu-west-1-r-w.amazonaws.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php-fpm8.  39 www-data   27u  IPv4 322982      0t0     TCP ip-10-0-0-201.eu-west-1.compute.internal:34432->s3-eu-west-1-r-w.amazonaws.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php-fpm8.  39 www-data   28u  IPv4 322961      0t0     TCP ip-10-0-0-201.eu-west-1.compute.internal:34388->s3-eu-west-1-r-w.amazonaws.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php-fpm8.  39 www-data   30u  IPv4 322978      0t0     TCP ip-10-0-0-201.eu-west-1.compute.internal:34424->s3-eu-west-1-r-w.amazonaws.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php-fpm8.  39 www-data   31u  IPv4 322962      0t0     TCP ip-10-0-0-201.eu-west-1.compute.internal:34390->s3-eu-west-1-r-w.amazonaws.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php-fpm8.  39 www-data   32u  IPv4 322983      0t0     TCP ip-10-0-0-201.eu-west-1.compute.internal:34434->s3-eu-west-1-r-w.amazonaws.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php-fpm8.  39 www-data   33u  IPv4 322968      0t0     TCP ip-10-0-0-201.eu-west-1.compute.internal:34404->s3-eu-west-1-r-w.amazonaws.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php-fpm8.  39 www-data   34u  IPv4 322985      0t0     TCP ip-10-0-0-201.eu-west-1.compute.internal:34438->s3-eu-west-1-r-w.amazonaws.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php-fpm8.  39 www-data   35u  IPv4 322984      0t0     TCP ip-10-0-0-201.eu-west-1.compute.internal:34436->s3-eu-west-1-r-w.amazonaws.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php-fpm8.  39 www-data   36u  IPv4 322969      0t0     TCP ip-10-0-0-201.eu-west-1.compute.internal:34406->s3-eu-west-1-r-w.amazonaws.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php-fpm8.  39 www-data   37u  IPv4 322986      0t0     TCP ip-10-0-0-201.eu-west-1.compute.internal:34440->s3-eu-west-1-r-w.amazonaws.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

PHP Version: 8.0.9
Curl version: 7.58.0
Guzzle version: 6.x

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue using webdav storage for laravel. Were you able to find a solution?